# unrecognized selector sent to instance error when a button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

I'm not entirely sure why I am getting this error. It occurs when I click the button on my FirstViewController:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FirstViewController 1ButtonPress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10954bbd0'
```

My FirstViewController has a button (1ButtonPress) which performs a segue with another ViewController which has a embed NavigationController (so in my storyboard, the segue is from FirstViewController to the NavigationController). On this segue, some data is transferred to the other ViewController by:
**First.m**

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"abc"]) {
            UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
            SecondViewController *BVC = (SecondViewController *)(navController.topViewController);
        BVC.BLLImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage.jpg"];
        BVC.BLLTitle = @"SomeText";
    }

}
```

The segue has the identifier "abc" in storyboard. Looking around it, I believe it has something to do with an incorrect class, but everything on first inspection looks fine. 
Any other reason why I would be getting this error?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `1ButtonPress`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go through the error you saw. It says that an unrecognized selector was sent to an instance of `FirstViewController`.

From what I deduce, you hooked up your button to your view controller, and removed the implementation from your view controller later, assuming that it'd remove the connection you earlier created from your button to your view controller. Unfortunately, that's not how it works. You need to remove the connection from the button too.

To do that, right click on your button in the storyboard, and remove the connection which says `1ButtonPress:`.

Side note: You're doing too much for a beginner to understand. Please try going through the Cocoa world step by step. Also, read up [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) to learn about how to name your methods and variables in a more easy-to-understand way.

Comment: That was it, I ended up getting another error after that:
"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key givenName" 
But I realized I had change the name of the outlet without re-linking it in the storyboard. So fixed that and all is well.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the `1ButtonPress` button in your Storyboard. Remove the action to `1ButtonPress:`.