# Logout Button crash

Tags: swift, xcode

I just implemented a logout button on my HeaderView sector. But somehow I keep getting this crash from Xcode.

I feel like this is somehow related to my `func logoutBtnClicked(){***}`.

so here is what my logoutBtnClicked() looks like:

```
//clicked logout
    @IBAction func logout(sender: AnyObject) {

        PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("username")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                let signin = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("signinViewController") as! SigninViewController
                let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = signin
            }
        }
    }
```

---

> 2016-08-18 21:18:54.801 helloworld[2439:115160] -[helloworld.HomeViewController Logout:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e38840
>       2016-08-18 21:18:54.829 helloworld[2439:115160] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[helloworld.HomeViewController Logout:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e38840'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (
>           0   CoreFoundation                      0x018d1494 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
>           1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x035e5e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
>           2   CoreFoundation                      0x018db253 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
>           3   CoreFoundation                      0x0181089d ___forwarding_** + 1037
>           4   CoreFoundation                      0x0181046e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
>           5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x035fa0b5 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
>           6   UIKit                               0x020c1e38 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
>           7   UIKit                               0x025519da -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 179
>           8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x035fa0b5 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
>           9   UIKit                               0x020c1e38 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
>           10  UIKit                               0x020c1db7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
>           11  UIKit                               0x02265f3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 79
>           12  UIKit                               0x022662d4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 433
>           13  UIKit                               0x02266483 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 864
>           14  UIKit                               0x022652c1 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 714
>           15  UIKit                               0x0214252e -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1095
>           16  UIKit                               0x021435cc -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1159
>           17  UIKit                               0x020e4be8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 266
>           18  UIKit                               0x020b9769 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7795
>           19  CoreFoundation                      0x017e3e5f **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
>           20  CoreFoundation                      0x017d9aeb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
>           21  CoreFoundation                      0x017d8f08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
>           22  CoreFoundation                      0x017d8846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>           23  CoreFoundation                      0x017d865b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
>           24  GraphicsServices                    0x05f27664 GSEventRunModal + 192
>           25  GraphicsServices                    0x05f274a1 GSEventRun + 104
>           26  UIKit                               0x020bfeb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
>           27  helloworld                              0x0007a4e1 main + 145
>           28  libdyld.dylib                       0x043bba25 start + 1
>       )
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>       (lldb)

Comment: Error reports unrecognized selector sent to instance - its not hooked up to the correct view controller

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588690/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error-when-a-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the `interface builder` for `HomeViewController`, for button  action you have set `Logout` and inside the class of `HomeViewController` it is declare as `logout`, `action` and `property` are `case sensitive`, so either change one of them will solve your crash.